# Snap bluez on Rasperry Pi 3 - "no default controller"

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, bluez

When trying to install bluez (5.44-2) on ubuntu 16.04 IoT Core bluez.bluetoothctl cannot find any default controller?

```
$ snap interfaces | grep blue
bluez:service             bluez:client
:bluetooth-control        -
:uhid                     bluez
-                         bluez:bluetooth-control
-                         bluez:home
-                         bluez:network-c

>$ systemctl status snap.bluez.bluez.service
● snap.bluez.bluez.service - Service for snap application bluez.bluez
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap.bluez.bluez.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-06-30 05:58:43 UTC; 21min ago
 Main PID: 1385 (bluetoothd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/snap.bluez.bluez.service
           └─1385 /snap/bluez/86/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -E
```

When launching bluez.bluetoothctl it responds with

```
 Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...
```

When trying to e.g. set it to be discoverable

```
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
No default controller available
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Solved it :-) - found some info here:  [link]https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1674509 - and the solution is to run `sudo /snap/bin/hciattach /dev/ttyAMA0 bcm43xx 921600 noflow -`